# Finding Marginal Effects of Logistic Regression Coefficents

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients, marginal-effect

I used a logistic regression model to predict the probability of a fruit being a pomegranate or not with the explanatory variables as the number of seeds and the ounces it weights. My coefficients were estimated as follows: $\beta_{seeds}=0.38$, $\beta_{ounces}=0.092$, with a slope of $-43$. I wanted to find if the marginal effect of an additional seed on the probability being a pomegranate higher for a fruit with $104$ seeds that weights $28$ ounces or a fruit with $112$ seeds that weighs $23$ ounces.

I plugged the coefficients and inputs into the equation $(P=1)=\frac{e^{f(x)}}{1+e^{f(x)}}$ where $f(x)=-43+\beta_{seeds}*Seeds+\beta_{ounces}*Ounces$ to have the following:

A) For 104 and 105 seeds with 28 ounces. We have the respective $f(seeds=104,ounces=28)=-0.904$ and $f(seeds=105,ounces=28)=-0.524$, which means their respective probabilities being a pomegranate are $28.82%$ and $37.19%$ respectively. So a difference of $8.37%$

B) For 112 and 113 seeds with 23 ounces. We have the respective $f(seeds=112,ounces=23)=1.676$ and $f(seeds=113,ounces=23)=2.056$, which means their respective probabilities being a pomegranate are $84.23%$ and $88.66%$ respectively. So a difference of $4.42%$

Therefore I said the marginal effect of an additional seeds on the probability of a fruit being a pomegranate was higher on the fruit with 104 seeds and 28 ounces.  Is this process correct?